# How to Open Files in Default Windows Apps for a FTP Server added as a Network Location?

Tags: windows, windows-10, ftp, android

I've installed "WiFi FTP Server" mobile app on my Android phone which allows your phone to run as a FTP Server.

When I add a network location in Windows 10, it works fine and I can see/browse the folders on my Android phone.

When I click on any file to open it, for example a ".jpg" image file, instead of the file opening using the default Windows 10 Photos app/program, the only options presented are the web browsers I have installed, see screenshot:

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHwl1.png)

Is there any way to make the files open using the default Windows 10 apps?

If I drag the file and copy it to Desktop and then click to open, it opens in the default app at that point but I would like to open them without having to copy them to my computer.

Tried deleting the network location and re-adding it.

Comment: What path (full URL) have you used for adding your Android device as network share? Based on your description it is not via SMB/CIFS protocol.

Comment: I have used: "ftp://192.168.8.200:2221" as this is what is shown to me as the Server URL in the Android app (WiFi FTP Server), is this correct?

Comment: I have used: "ftp : // 192.168.8.200:2221" - without the spaces (the previous post automatically removed the "ftp://" from the URL after I posted it)

Comment: If you want to access the Android file like they were on your local PC you need an app that provides them via SMB/CIFS not FTP. Windows does not provide a fully seamless FTP integration.

Comment: Oh, that's surprising, thought windows would just see a ".jpg" extension and then use the default app for opening the file. I just installed and tried with android app "Cx File Explorer" from Play Store but has the same issue. Can you recommend an app that should work? or advise what to look for?

Comment: Protocols like FTP, WebDAV, MTP and so on don't allow random access within a file which is necessary for directly accessing files through applications. Therefore every protocol implementation contains it's own code to download the file to a temp dir and then open it somehow. You need an app providing the Android data as SMB2 share. But because of the new storage model since Android 11 I don't think that you will find a working app if you have Android 11+ for accessing the shared "sdcard" folder.

Comment: I'm not accessing sdcard data, just wanted to access the default phone directory/folders wirelessly without having to plug USB cable in every time. Oh well, I guess it's not possible then, thank you for helping Robert!

Comment: The default shared storage `/storage/emulated/0` also has the alias `/sdcard`. /sdcard is not the sdcard, it was once the sdcard (on Android 2.x) and now it is called so for historical reason, but the default path is still `/sdcard. The sdcard is the external storage.